# Run page after form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I try to describe this problem as clear as possible.

I have an application where there is a form with some switches.
When i submit this form, the form will update an XML file with the new information.

After submitting that information, the website needs to target a page just to run, not to visit.

Example:

```js
 window.open("http://user:alarm@10.2.2.5/reload/functions.php");
```

The only problem here is that:
1. It doesnt run the script because the page reloads automaticly when submitting the form.
2. The user of the website visits the page, but it only needs to be run.

Someone know an fix for this?

Best Regards,
Kris

Comment: use AJAX with a good reference and example

Comment: Hi Dickens,
Do you have an example or tutorial?

Comment: The best official documentation I know is Mozilla -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX